# Induced map on cohomology for a product space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, products, cross-product

Suppose we have connected CW complexes $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and a map $f:X \times Y \to Z$, and that $f$ maps $X \times \{y_0\}$ to $\{z_0\}$. Suppose furthermore that we take coefficients from a free R-module $R$ and $H^k(Y;R)$ is a finitely-generated free R-module for all $k$. Then, given any $n$, $f$ induces a map $f^*:H^n(Z,R) \to H^n(X \times Y,R)$. $H^n(X \times Y,R)$ then splits as a sum $\sum_{i=0}^n H^i(X;R)\otimes_R H^{n-i}(Y;R)$ for R-module $R$. Given any $\alpha \in H^n(Z;R)$, is there a way to show that the $i=0$ summand in the splitting of $f^*(\alpha)$ is zero? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: In order to use the Kunneth formula you need some assumption on the cohmology of $X,Y$ it is not true in general.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the condition of finite generation.

Comment: the problem is if the cohomology is not torsion free since then in the kunneth formula you need to take the sum of the $Tor$ part.

Comment: in example --- projection $S^1\times S^2\to S^2$, for $\alpha$ is the generator of $H^2(S^2)$, $f^*(\alpha)=1\otimes\alpha$ --- what do you want to show?

Comment: Under the conditions of the problem, $H^2(S^1 \times S^2;R)$ can be decomposed as the sum $\sum_{i=0}^2 H^i(S^1;R)\otimes_R H^{n-i}(S^2;R)$. $f^*(\alpha)$ can be expressed, in this decomposition, as $0+0+1 \otimes \alpha$. The first zero in the sum corresponds to the $i=0$ summand and is, as we would expect, zero. I am simply trying to generalize this result.

Comment: By generalize I mean that, for $f:X \times Y \to Z$ such that $X \times {y_0}$ is mapped to ${z_0}$, $f^*(\alpha)$, when decomposed as a sum $\sum_{i=0}^n H^i(X) \otimes H^{n-i}(Y)$, has zero contribution from the $H^n(X) \otimes H^0(Y)$ summand.